# redis value pairs in set

Tags: c, redis, set

I know redis does not allow nested structures but here is what I do:

add value pairs into a set as string :
SADD myset %lu:%ld

then read them with (after a SMEMBERS myset):

sscanf(conn->reply->element[i]->str,"%lu:%ld",&myfirstvalue,&mysecondvalue );

this works but I realized keeping values as string in a set uses too much memory.

Is there a better way to store this unsigned long long , long long pair in a set ?

Answer (score 0):

What about save as raw bytes? Both unsigned long long and long long are 64bits, which is 8 bytes long. So with 16bytes, you should be able to save any pair. Converting the 16bytes to a unsigned char array would serve your purpose.

Note that this would introduce some performance hit as after you "encode" before add value pairs, you'll need to "decode" when retrieving it. As you are doing so with saved string, I doubt the suggested solution would be slower, if not faster in fact.

Comment: In redis memory optimization page  It says : "Since Redis 2.2 many data types are optimized to use less space up to a certain size. Hashes, Lists, Sets composed of just integers, and Sorted Sets, when smaller than a given number of elements, and up to a maximum element size, are encoded in a very memory efficient way that uses up to 10 times less memory (with 5 time less memory used being the average saving)." http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization does it apply when I use 16 byte binary data?

Comment: @Berk Sorry but I'm not familiar with redis. I see what the documentation listed are mostly high level data structures. In the sense that sets composed of just integers are optimized, my guess is they are referring to optimizing the storage overhead for each set element. 16 byte binary is 4 32bit integer or 2 64bit integer but to take advantage of the optimized set storage, it can not be saved as a unity I guess. On top of that, there's the question what "given number of elements" and "maximum element size" exactly are...